# Проблема подключения к хосту с SSL сертификатом

Tags: php, ssl

В чем может быть причина такого поведения этого куска кода - у других запросы выполняются, домен доступен с сертификатом, а у меня нет? Проверяли огромное количество вариантов - начиная от окружения, заканчивая моими тестами на win (сейчас ubuntu). 
PHP - от 5.6 до 7.2, OpenSSL 1.1.0h

```
 $context = stream_context_create(
        array(
            'ssl' => array(
                'verify_peer' => true,
                'local_cert' => $cert_file,
                'cafile' => $ca_file,
                'passphrase' => '123456',
            ),
        )
    );
file_get_contents($loc, false, $context);
```

Ошибка:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(): Unable to set local cert chain file `/var/www/empirethx/source/config/files/CFT/certificate_dev/test_api_36022_1.pem'; Check that your cafile/capath settings include details of your certificate and its issuer in /var/www/empirethx/source/init.php on line 160

Warning: file_get_contents(): Failed to enable crypto in /var/www/empirethx/source/init.php on line 160

Warning: file_get_contents(some url....): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/empirethx/source/init.php on line 160
```

Выделял этот кусок кода в отдельный файл, запускал от sudo, менял права на серты, ставил чистый php, делал запрос через разные версии php, переустанавливал курл, openssl, ca-certs. Стоял криптопро - удалил. Ничего не помогает.

**UPD** - При использовании curl запроса через PHP проблем не возникает, поэтому могу предположить, что дело именно в stream_context_create. Есть идеи?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81223/discussion-on-question-by-------ssl-).